# Строка возвращается не до конца

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не проходит 5ую проверку , возвращает No h ,вместо No hi

```
def between_markers(text , begin , end )  :

    if text.find(begin)==-1:
        final= text[:text.find(end)]
    elif text.find(end)==-1:
          final= text[text.find(begin)+len(begin):]
    elif text.find(begin)==-1 and text.find(end)==-1:
         final= text
    elif text.find(begin)>text.find(end):
        final= ''
    else:
        final= text[text.find(begin)+len(begin):text.find(end)]

    return final 



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Example:')
    print(between_markers('What is >apple<', '>', '<'))

    # These "asserts" are used for self-checking and not for testing
    assert between_markers('What is >apple<', '>', '<') == "apple", "One sym"
    assert between_markers("<head><title>My new site</title></head>",
                           "<title>", "</title>") == "My new site", "HTML"
    assert between_markers('No[/b] hi', '[b]', '[/b]') == 'No', 'No opened'
    assert between_markers('No [b]hi', '[b]', '[/b]') == 'hi', 'No close'
    assert between_markers('No hi', '[b]', '[/b]') == 'No hi', 'No markers at all'
    assert between_markers('No <hi>', '>', '<') == '', 'Wrong direction'
    print('Wow, you are doing pretty good. Time to check it!')
```

Comment: Неплохо бы рассказать, что должна делать функция, чтоб не приходилось вычислять.

Comment: Запустите отладчик и все станет очевидно, хотя бы банальный принт в каждую ветку. Код делает то, что в нем написано. Просто в нем написано не то, что вам нужно

Comment: Вам дана строка и два маркера (начальный и конечный). Вам необходимо найти текст, заключенный между двумя этими маркерами. Но есть несколько важных условий:

Начальный и конечный маркеры всегда разные
Если нет начального маркера, то началом считать начало строки
Если нет конечного маркера, то концом считать конец строки
Если нет ни конечного, ни начального маркеров, то просто вернуть всю строку
Если конечный маркер стоит перед начальным, то вернуть пустую строку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получается, что на пятой проверке ваш запрос

```
between_markers('No hi', '[b]', '[/b]')
```

соответствует первому условию функции between_markers:

```
if text.find(begin) == -1:
    final = text[:text.find(end)]
```

Разобьем на части и все сразу станет понятно.
Значения переменных:

```
text = 'No hi'  
end = '[/b]'
```

Шаг 1:

```
'No hi'.find('[/b]')
```

Результат: -1

Шаг 2:

```
'No hi'[:-1]
```

Результат: 'No h'

Думаю теперь вам станет проще :)
На самом деле все тоже самое делает любой дебагер. Рекомендую вам им воспользоваться.

Comment: Спасибо , за ответ , теперь все понятно)

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто, в коде поменяны местами условия. Первым условием должно быть отсутствие маркеров. У вас это стоит 2 elif.

```
def between_markers(text , begin , end )  :

    if text.find(begin)==-1 and text.find(end)==-1:
         final= text
    elif text.find(begin)==-1:
        final= text[:text.find(end)]
    elif text.find(end)==-1:
          final= text[text.find(begin)+len(begin):]
    elif text.find(begin)>text.find(end):
        final= ''
    else:
        final= text[text.find(begin)+len(begin):text.find(end)]

    return final 



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Example:')
    print(between_markers('What is >apple<', '>', '<'))

    # These "asserts" are used for self-checking and not for testing
    assert between_markers('What is >apple<', '>', '<') == "apple", "One sym"
    assert between_markers("<head><title>My new site</title></head>",
                           "<title>", "</title>") == "My new site", "HTML"
    assert between_markers('No[/b] hi', '[b]', '[/b]') == 'No', 'No opened'
    assert between_markers('No [b]hi', '[b]', '[/b]') == 'hi', 'No close'
    assert between_markers('No hi', '[b]', '[/b]') == 'No hi', 'No markers at all'
    assert between_markers('No <hi>', '>', '<') == '', 'Wrong direction'
    print('Wow, you are doing pretty good. Time to check it!')
```